# "mov eax, dword ptr fs:loc_12+6" Which value has been assigned to eax?

Tags: assembly

I wonder which value has beed assigned to eax when the following code block executed?

```
mov     eax, dword ptr fs:loc_12+6
```

Dumped data if necessary:

```
00000012  0F B6 83 1B 47 40 00 0B  C0 75 0A B8 F8 FF FF FF
```

**Edit:** Processor is x86, OS is Windows

Answer (score 2):

Your disassembler assigned a value to loc_12 which we don't know, and you're not saying what platform this is, but on Windows, anything to do with the fs: register generally has to do with the thread information block ([TIB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block)).

Most likely, it's reading from the exception handler chain or reading the stack limit or thread id - the actual offset used in the instruction should let you find out on the page I referred to.

Comment: I am just asking if the value that assigned to eax is "(0F B6 83 1B) + 6" or "00 0B C0 75"

Comment: If your data dump starts at fs:[12], eax should become 75c00b00.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to tell the value of `eax` after this instruction without knowing:

- the segment base address of the segment that `fs` points to
- the offset encoded in the instruction, the value of that `loc_12+6` constant
- what is in the memory at address `segment base address + offset encoded in the instruction`